# Make a (copy of a) postgis database available to customer?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgis, windows-server

Our application uses a PostgreSQL database (with the PostGIS spatial extension). Now one of our customers has requested direct access to the database; because, as they claim, it’s their data.

We’d rather not provide direct access to the database, because a wrong query might end up killing (or temporarily disabling) the database server, resulting in downtime for our application, or even a corrupt database.

Instead, we were thinking of setting up a slave database, and replicate the master. The slave would then only be used for read-only querying, so doesn’t need to write back to the master.

What is the easiest method of doing this with Postgres, while working with PostGIS as well? Or is a daily data dump easier to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's one time setup, I think dump would be easiest. But if You need your update be available on customer, then I think streaming replication would be easier, set up once and no need to update in the future as the replication will handle the data updates.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html

Comment: It's not a one-time thing; the customer wants to have it available and updated at all time; a day old would be OK, but not much more.

Comment: I mean one time set up, but still available for the next usage

Comment: it’s for a single database, if that’s what you mean.

Comment: I mean, restore from the dump, could be for many databases, and You can use the restored database as long as You want.

Comment: But the dump would get old pretty fast, so we'd have to do a fresh dump about once a day. I’ll read up on streaming replication.

Comment: If that's the case, then streaming replication would be a better solution IMO